# Postfix check hosted sender domain

Tags: postfix, smtp

On my server I have this problem: there are mails sent from, example, johndoe@domain.com even if domain.com isn't hosted on my server. And, obviously, there is no johndoe@domain.com among the e-mail accounts on my server.

I have Plesk over Postfix and I set the "server requires authentication" label with the "SMTP" checkbox. But how can johndoe@domain.com grant access if it's not listed on my server?

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Administration panels are off-topic on Server Fault.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is a basic function of SMTP, there is no control over who a person can send as, unless of course you set it up.

There is an inbuilt functionality in postfix that will allow you to only let people send with the From email address(es) you specify. You do however need to have SASL enabled (which is what authentication normally is).

To add it into your setup, you will need a few pieces, first you'll need to add an SQL query, this one would basically only allow people to send as their email as listed in the `postfix_users` table (assuming you only want them to use one email, otherwise you might want to select it from another table).

`SELECT email FROM postfix_users WHERE email LIKE '%s';`

Then you'll want to define that SQL query as your `smtp_sender_login_maps`

Then under `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` you'll need to add the line line `reject_sender_login_mismatch,` usually right before `permit_sasl_authenticated`.

This will then ensure that the user is sending authenticated mail, and that the email in the FROM field matches the email in their user profile.

BTW, you are sure that this email originates outside your server, correct?

Comment: Thank for your help! About your last line, I have checked that all the accounts aren't compromised. Anyway, I can't log if the mails come from a PHP script...I tried different solutions, but none of them worked for me. I'll try the above solution and let you know ;) Thanks!

Comment: Don't use my query verbatim, I'm working from memory, so my script could have errors or typoes :)

Comment: If you look through the mail log, you should be able to see where the mail originates from, if it's localhost, or the IP address of the server, what I've suggested here won't fix it :)